# How to parse Dynatree JSON variable?

Tags: java, jquery, playframework, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am using Dynatree plugin in play 2.0 (Java).

They specified  `var dict = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").toDict();`  to save whole tree into single variable in form of JSON Object.

I am converting it to string by using `JSON.stringify(dict);` and I am returning string to controller.

As the whole tree is present in one variable it is becoming hard to parse and save the values into database. I tried with JSONParser, Gson libraries, but I cannot parse the tree.

I think someone has already solved this problem. Could anyone suggest me how to parse this JSONtree variable of dynatree?